# Google Charts add in second line in chart

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

In google charts I am creating a line chart to show the relationship between runs/fails. The code below works to only draw the first part of the line chart being "Runs", and forgetting about the "Fails" column. Since I am not hard coding in my data I am not sure on how to use the example from the Google Charts documentation, found [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart).

-- Which shows that they use .addcolumn() and .addrows() but not sure where to implement.

-- When I look at the developer's console on chrome, nothing in there indicates an error.

If anyone has done something like this and can point me in the right direction, it would be awesome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Name', 'RunDate', 'Runs', 'Fails'],
                <?php
                    $dbName = "my_test";
                    $config = parse_ini_file("myconfig.ini",true);
                    $dbUser = $config["DB"]["db_user"];
                    $dbServer = $config["DB"]["db_ip"];
                    $dbPassword = $config["DB"]["db_pass"];

                    $con = mysql_connect($dbServer, $dbUser, $dbPassword);

                    if (!$con) {
                        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                    }

                    mysql_select_db($dbName, $con);

                    $sql = mysql_query("select * from GraphTest");

                    $output = array();

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        // create a temp array to hold the data
                        $temp = array();

                        // add the data
                        $temp[] = '"' . $row['Name'] . '"';
                        $temp[] = '"' . $row['RunDate'] . '"';
                        $temp[] = (int) $row['Runs'];
                        $temp[] = (int) $row['Fails'];
                        // implode the temp array into a comma-separated list and add to the output array
                        $output[] = '[' . implode(', ', $temp) . ']';
                    }
                    // implode the output into a comma-newline separated list and echo
                    echo implode(",\n", $output);

                    mysql_close($con);
                ?>
            ]);

            // parse the data table for a list of locations
            var locations = google.visualization.data.group(data, [0], []);
            // build an array of data column definitions
            var columns = [1];
            for (var i = 0; i < locations.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
                var loc = locations.getValue(i, 0);
                columns.push({
                    label: loc,
                    type: 'number',
                    calc: function (dt, row) {
                        // include data in this column only if the location matches
                        return (dt.getValue(row, 0) == loc) ? dt.getValue(row, 2) : null;
                    }
                });
            }

            // create a DataView based on the DataTable to get the correct snapshot of the data for the chart
            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            // set the columns in the view to the columns we constructed above
            view.setColumns(columns);

            var options = {
                title: 'data test',
                curveType: 'function'
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            // draw the chart using the DataView instead of the DataTable
            chart.draw(view, options);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
```

Output (Showing only Runs):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when building the columns array for the data view,
the Fails column is never referenced, only Runs...

from the `calc` function...

```
// only Runs, column 2 is used
return (dt.getValue(row, 0) == loc) ? dt.getValue(row, 2) : null;
```

to get data from Fails, add another column...

```
  // Runs
  columns.push({
      label: loc,
      type: 'number',
      calc: function (dt, row) {
          // include data in this column only if the location matches
          return (dt.getValue(row, 0) == loc) ? dt.getValue(row, 2) : null;
      }
  });

  // Fails
  columns.push({
      label: loc,
      type: 'number',
      calc: function (dt, row) {
          // include data in this column only if the location matches
          return (dt.getValue(row, 0) == loc) ? dt.getValue(row, 3) : null;
      }
  });
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Name', 'RunDate', 'Runs', 'Fails'],
    ['A', '2018-05-10', 5000, 6000],
    ['A', '2018-05-11', 6000, 5000],
    ['A', '2018-05-12', 7000, 6000],
    ['A', '2018-05-13', 8000, 5000],
    ['A', '2018-05-14', 9000, 6000],
  ]);

  var locations = google.visualization.data.group(data, [0], []);
  var columns = [1];
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      var loc = locations.getValue(i, 0);
      addColumn(loc);
  }

  function addColumn(loc) {
      columns.push({
          label: loc,
          type: 'number',
          calc: function (dt, row) {
              // include data in this column only if the location matches
              return (dt.getValue(row, 0) == loc) ? dt.getValue(row, 2) : null;
          }
      });
      columns.push({
          label: loc,
          type: 'number',
          calc: function (dt, row) {
              // include data in this column only if the location matches
              return (dt.getValue(row, 0) == loc) ? dt.getValue(row, 3) : null;
          }
      });
  }

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns(columns);

  var options = {
    title: 'data test',
    curveType: 'function'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```